# How get something from Parse.com database?

Tags: parse-platform

How show something from parse.com data base ? Give me code please. I just only sturted learning js. For example how show all users. Or how show information about one user. Help please )

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is not for 'gimme the codez'. Attempt to solve the issue yourself and if you run into a specific problem, come back and ask about it.

Answer (score 1):

Hi I would suggest you to start learning parse ans JS with all the proper documentation provided. [Documentations](https://parse.com/docs/js/guide)

If you are looking for a simple example using Parse and JS, take a look at the below code,

```
myObject.fetch({
    success: function(myObject) {
       // The object was refreshed successfully.
    },
    error: function(myObject, error) {
       // The object was not refreshed successfully.
       // error is a Parse.Error with an error code and message.
    }
});
```

Or you can refer to the below example also, where we can make use of handlebar.js to display each blog object.

```
$(function() {

      Parse.$ = jQuery;

      // Replace this line with the one on your Quickstart Guide Page
      Parse.initialize("KEYS", "KEYS");
      // Your Parse application key

      var Blog = Parse.Object.extend("Blog");
      var Blogs = Parse.Collection.extend({
          model: Blog
      });
      var blogs = new Blogs();
      blogs.fetch({
           success: function(blogs){
               console.log(blogs);

               var blogsView = new BlogsView({ collection: blogs });
               blogsView.render();
               $('.main-container').html(blogsView.el);
            },
            error: function(blog, error){
               console.log(error);_
            }
     });

     var BlogsView =  Parse.View.extend({
            template: Handlebars.compile($('#blogs-tpl').html()),
            render: function(){ 
            var collection = { blog: this.collection.toJSON() };
            this.$el.html(this.template(collection));
            }
     });
});
```